# How to iterate over arrays stored in a list and dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I want to iterate over numpy arrays stored in a list and a dictionray. My list is named as `result`:

```
    result= [array([[ 1.        ,  0.75      , 69.5198822 ],
            ...,
            [99.        , 29.25      , 49.51967621]]),
                       ...
     array([[ 1.        ,  0.75      , 78.88569641],
            ...,
            [99.        , 29.25      , 58.88546753]]),
                       ...
     array([[ 1.        ,  0.75      , 77.7075882 ],
            ...,
            [99.        , 29.25      , 57.70734406]])]
```

My dictionary is also named `dicti` :

```
    {'sub_arr1': array([[37.        ,  2.25      ,  2.62501693],
            ...,
            [81.68138123, 29.25      , 99.        ]]),
                          ...
     'sub_arr2': array([[41.        ,  2.25      ,  2.254704  ],
            ...,
            [85.93613434, 29.25      , 99.        ]]),
                          ...
     'sub_arr3': array([[51.        ,  2.25      ,  1.13132851],
            ...,
            [96.60651398, 29.25      , 99.        ]])}
```

Than, I want to do a calculation between arrays stored in these two data sets (`result` and `dicti`). I want to delete some data points of arrays of `result` that are closer than a threshold (e.g. 10) to arrays of `dicti` and store them as a new one. In fact, I want to compare the first array of `result` to the first array of `dicti`, second with second, third with third and so on. I can say I want to clean arrays stored in `result` list, then save the new clean arrays as separate ones in a 3d numpy array or a maybe again a list of cleaned arrays.  My code (that is not working!!!) is as bellow:

```
import numpy as np    
new_result=np.array ([])
    for i in result:
        for key, value in dicti():
            clp=result[i][np.where(np.min(distance.cdist(value, result[i]),axis=0)<10)[0],:] # it finds the points of result that are closer 10 to points stored as values of dicti
            cleaned_result= npi.difference(result[i], clp) # it removes that close points
            new_result=np.append (new_result, cleaned_result).
```

The error I am facing is `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` but I think my code has also other issues.
In advance I appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
import numpy as np    
new_result=np.array ([])
for res, value in zip(result, dicti.values()):
    clp=res[np.where(np.min(distance.cdist(value, res),axis=0)<10)[0],:] # it finds the points of result that are closer 10 to points stored as values of dicti
    cleaned_result= npi.difference(res, clp) # it removes that close points
    new_result=np.append (new_result, cleaned_result).
```

`zip` is a function that takes two or more iterators and returns in each iteration a tuple where each element is taken from each iterator.

For example:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = {'A':'a', 'B':'b', 'C':'c'}
for x, y in zip(a, b.values()):
     print(x, y)
```

This shows as output:

```sh
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

`zip` reproduces exactly what you say:

> I want to compare the first array of result to the first array of dicti, second with second, third with third and so on

Comment: dear @Jorge Morgado, I deeply do appreciate your help. at the moment, the `new_result` is a numpy array of all the iterations. Do you know a way to separate each iteration? I mean somthing like my primary list (`result`) but a numpy array. And if it is not possible to store them as numpy array, is it possible to save outcome of each iteration as separate components of a list? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what do you mean by: "separate each iteration", Can you explain that in a little more detailed way?

Comment: My primary list named as `result` have e.g. three arrays and also my dictionary.values are also three. Code adds each cleared array after another one, but I want to have separate arrays like the arrays of  `result`. Each iteration of for loop is cleaning one array of `result` based on dictionary values. For example, `result` is a list of three arrays with different sizes (like 100x3, 50x3 and 80x3). By cleaning it (e.g. half of points are deleted) I want to have the one as a list of numpy array with this size= 50x3, 25x3 and 40x3 ore preferably I want a 3d numpy array having these three ones.

Comment: so basically what you want is modify the array `result` in place and as a numpy array?

Comment: As a numpy array which the results of each iteration are stored separately or a list like the original list that has separate arrays. The point is that I want to separate arrays as members of a list (like original `result`) or keep them as sub-components of a numpy array. The key point is that I do not want to mix them and put them altogether in a for example in a 105x3 numpy array (made by cleaned arrays: 50x3, 25x3 and 40x3, I assumed them from my previous comment). or a list of three arays which the first one is 50x3, the second 25x3 and the third one 40x3.

Comment: ohhhhh i get it....i tell you now, give me a few minutes

Comment: Well an easy way is declaring `new_result` as a typical python list. Then you append to `new_result` the cleaned numpy arrays (`new_result.append(cleanded_result)`) and at the end you convert `new_result` to a numpy array (`new_result = np.array(new_result)`)

Comment: sorry for taking that much time, but I face an error: `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`. At the start, I should define my new result as a list (`new_result=[]`) or a numpy array (`new_result=np.array ([])`)?

Comment: to be able to do `new_result.append(...)`,  `new_result` must be a python list, not a numpy array...so you must defined as: `new_result = []`. And at the end when all the data is inside you do: `new_result = np.array(new_result)`

Comment: sorry, but when I run the code, an error says: `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`.

Comment: Enter [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222797/how-to-iterate-over-arrays-stored-in-a-list-and-dictionary) and show me the code